# How to make R output text details about a dendrogram object?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, dendrogram

Please see my previous question for details relating to test data and commands used to create a dendrogram: [Using R to cluster based on euclidean distance and a complete linkage metric, too many vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31441846/using-r-to-cluster-based-on-euclidean-distance-and-a-complete-linkage-metric-to)

Here is a quick summary of my commands to make the dendrogram:

```
un_exprs <- as.matrix(read.table("sample.txt", header=TRUE, sep = "\t", row.names = 1, as.is=TRUE))
exprs <- t(un_exprs)
eucl_dist=dist(exprs,method = 'euclidean')
hie_clust=hclust(eucl_dist, method = 'complete')\
dend <- as.dendrogram(hie_clust)
plot(dend)
```

This makes a very nice dengrogram plot. However, lets say this dendrogram has 2 clusters... I want to get a text list of each element belonging to each of the 2 clusters. I'm assuming this is trivial, but I don't have enough experience with R for this to be intuitive. Thanks!

Comment: `cutree(hie_clust,k=2)`

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Turn the comment into an answer if you'd solving credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compute this from the `hclust` return with `stats::cutree`

```
cutree(hie_clust,k=2)
```