# R: Extracting cluster elements from a dendrogram

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I have a dendrogram split into 4 clusters. I want to extract the cluster membership for each element in a table. Can someone please advise?

```
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "complete")
par(cex=0.7, mar=c(5, 8, 4, 1))
plot(hc, xlab="", ylab="", main="", sub="", axes=FALSE)
par(cex=1)
title(xlab="", ylab="", main="Violent crime rates by US state")
axis(2)
rect.hclust(hc,k=4, border = 3:4)
```

Comment: Thank you @scoa. I tried to create a data frame with the State and Cluster_ID. d = data.frame(State = c(row.names(USArrests)),Cluster_ID = cutree(hc,k=4)). The thing is the State names are being displayed twice (in 2 columns). Can you please advise on how to remove one set of State names?

Comment: one is the variable `d$State` and the other one is the row names, which you can access with `row.names(d)`. You can either omit State from the data.frame creation (`d <- data.frame(Cluster_ID=cutree(hc,k=4))`) or use `row.names(d) <- NULL`

Comment: @scoa Why don't you just post as an answer??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make R output text details about a dendrogram object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31480427/how-to-make-r-output-text-details-about-a-dendrogram-object)